# Why can't I set this variable in an object with an object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

Why cant I do this I do not understand?

```
function hello() {
    this.say = 'fdfsd';
}
function goodbye() {
    this.example = new hello();
}
```

But it works if I do;

```
function hello() {
    this.say = 'fdfsd';
}
function goodbye() {
    this.example = false;
}
var goodbye = new goodbye();
goodbye.example = new hello();
```

Comment: What do you mean 'cant'?  new goodby() works for the first example

Comment: In my script I try to set a variable in an object with another object but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "it works" mean? What do you **expect** to happen? What **actually** happens?

Comment: It [works here](http://jsfiddle.net/KGUf4/1/), if you don't call the `goodbye like new goodbye()` then it won't work.

Comment: [Check this too](http://jsfiddle.net/KGUf4/2/).

Comment: I think `Aditya Manohar` answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to construct `goodbye`

```
var x = new goodbye();
```

Invoking the constructor will create a new object (of type `goodbye`).

This line will construct an object of type `hello` and assign it to the `example` attribute of the `goodbye` instance

```
this.example = new hello();
```

After construction this is what the instance of `goodbye` will contain

```
// x
{
    example: {
        say: "fdfsd"
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but try to improve with a few explanation, so `OP` can understand it clearly.